# Is there a limit to how many containers one can have in blob storage and seperate SAS policies

Tags: azure

In azure blob storage.

Is there a limit to the amount of blob storage containers within a storage account?

Is the amount of policies for SAS uris limited?

Reason for asking. I am considering if its possible to have a storage account and for each user in your application give them their own container and they can access it by a shared access signature.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is there a limit to the amount of blob storage containers within a
>   storage account?

No, there's no limit on the number of storage containers in a storage account. You're limited by the size of the storage account which was recently increased to `500 TB` from `200 TB`.

> Is the amount of policies for SAS uris limited?

As far as access policies go, there's a `limit of 5 access policies per container`. So if you're defining all SAS URI rules in your access policy, you could only create 5 SAS URIs per container. However if you're creating SAS URI without an access policy, I don't think there's a limit on the number of SAS URIs you could create.

Comment: Thanks. 5 is more then enough if its per container for this kind of usage. And maybe I dont even need policies and can just put out normal SAS uris without policy as long as the timeframe is below 60min if i recall correctly.

Comment: So 60 minute restriction in SAS URIs without policy was there long time back. Now you could have SAS URIs without access policy which can have an expiration time more than 60 minutes. See this link for this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn592123.aspx. HTH.

Comment: @GauravMantri I have a question about blob container's data limit. If I exceed 500TB of container limit what will happen with files which somebody wants to upload? Does new container (with the same name) will create by itself and files from both will be availabe or?

Comment: Update 2021: Maximum capacity is now 5 PiB

Comment: What would the maximum size limit be for each blob?

Comment: Here's where you can get the official/current info on this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#standard-storage-account-limits